# Jquery Validate a Day according to month selected

Tags: jquery, validation, datetime

What is the easiest way to validate a date using jquery so a user can not put 31st Feb example.

Code:

```
<select name="ddd" id="ddd">
    @for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
            <option @(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd")==i.ToString("D2") ? "selected='selected'" : "" )>@i.ToString("D2")</option>
    }
</select>
<select name="ddmy">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    {
            <option value="@DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("MMyyyy")">@DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("MMMM yyyy")</option>
    }
</select>
<select name="ddt">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        <option>@i.ToString("D2"):00</option>
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/12/validate-date-using-jquery.html

Hope that helps.

Happy jQuerying!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what "easiest" means. I would try to parse a date string constructed from the selected values and see if it is successful or not.